# Практика использования setTimeout

Tags: javascript, frontend

Я столкнулся с тем, что мои реализации на основе **setTimeout** очень нестабильны.

Самая частая проблема - **запуск функции на событие скролла**, без таймаутов функция запускается на каждый скролл, а с ним работает непредсказуемо. И, насколько я понял, в Chrome и Firefox логика работы таймаутов различается. 
http://javascript.ru/blog/subzey/firefox-settimeout

У меня возникли вопросы.

1. Хорошая ли это практика, использовать таймауты?
2. Что можно использовать вместо них?
3. Может существуют паттерны, которые позволяют не прибегать к использованию таймаутов?

Объясните, пожалуйста, на каких-нибудь примерах, как делается "по уму", в средних и больших проектах.

Может посоветуете литературу, в которой я смогу найти объяснения с примерами реализаций.

Comment: сложно что то так то

Comment: *И, насколько я понял, в Chrome и Firefox логика работы таймаутов различается.* - в чем различие, если не секрет?

Comment: То, что я нашёл на эту тему.
http://javascript.ru/blog/subzey/firefox-settimeout
http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~eparker/files/other/test_settimeout.html

Comment: уточните свой вопрос кодом, исполнение которого, по Вашему мнению, отличается в браузерах

Comment: У вас в вопросе ну очень древняя статья представлена. Рекомендую не опираться на такие старые данные.

Answer (score 1):

1. Использовать `setTimeout` нормальная практика.
2. На ряду с `setTimeout` можно использовать `setInterval`. Но все зависит от задачи поставленной.
3. Если хотите полное понимание `setTimeout` и вообще про микротаски то вам нужно понимать `event loop`. И лучшее объяснение для этого есть у Джейка Арчибальда. посмотрите [видео на ютубе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4_9BZezSUA).

Так же если вы решаете задачи связанные именно со скролом то есть слушатели событий для этого. Или можно воспользоваться rxJs бибилиотекой есть методы которые создают `observable` из событий. Так же в таких методых не забывайте о `debounce`. чтобы не вызвать перегрузки на странице.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку